# How to make activity or layout to display over other App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

> i want to open Youtube from my app, sound easy!! but at the same
> time i have to open my activity or layout on Youtube using display over other
> app.. How to achieve this ??[image: How to achieve this kind of thing??]